# Dism fails with error 3017

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, dism

I run Dism on windows server 2012 and I get error 3017 when run DISM.
In the log, I see:

```
2017-05-26 17:31:03, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=956 TID=2676 Failed to get the State of the Feature - CDISMPackageFeature::Internal_GetCbsState(hr:0x800f0902)
2017-05-26 17:31:03, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=956 TID=2676 Failed to get the CBS State of the Feature - CDISMPackageFeature::get_State(hr:0x800f0902)
2017-05-26 17:31:03, Error                 DISM   API: PID=1748 TID=2316 Failed to get feature state - DismFeature_InternalToPublicEx(hr:0x800f0902)
2017-05-26 17:31:03, Error                 DISM   API: PID=1748 TID=2316 Failed to transform 2 feature from internal to public - IDismFeatureCollection_InternalToPublicEx(hr:0x800f0902)
2017-05-26 17:31:03, Error                 DISM   API: PID=1748 TID=2316 Transform feature collection internal to public failed - CGetFeaturesCommandObject::InternalExecute(hr:0x800f0902)
2017-05-26 17:31:03, Error                 DISM   API: PID=1748 TID=2316 InternalExecute failed - CBaseCommandObject::Execute(hr:0x800f0902)
2017-05-26 17:31:03, Error                 DISM   API: PID=1748 TID=2888 CGetFeaturesCommandObject internal execution failed - DismGetFeaturesExInternal(hr:0x800f0902)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: 0x800f0902 should be CBS_E_BUSY, so the TrustedInstaller is busy. Which action/command do you try to run with DISM?